# DateTime.Parse - changes format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I'll try to illustrate an example:

```
var dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

**produces**: 10/01/2014 21:50:34

```
var dateNowParse = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

**produces**: 10/01/2014 9:50:34 PM

QUESTION:

*How to parse the date, and keep formatting like:* **dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss**, with an **24** hour format, without any PM

Thank you!

## Update 1

Sorry maybe my question wasn't so clear, i'll try to explain the real situation below.

Please do not focus on real meaning of `DateTime.Now`, suppose we have a `string` variable in the format of `10/01/2014 21:50:34`, and then I try to parse it, and store the result in another variable. What I am willing to achieve is to keep the result in a DateTime variable  which has the exact formatting `10/01/2014 21:50:34`.

Now here is a snippet:

```
var stringDate = "10/01/2014 22:50:30";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(stringDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
//parsedDate result is: 10/01/2014 10:50:30 PM
```

What is frustrating me is:

1. In the `stringDate` the `22:50` hour says that the string is formatted to the `24` hour clock. (*the 12 clock format uses hours counter up to 12*)
2. If I used 22:50, Isn't logically that the output should'nt use any AM PM and 12 hour format?

Comment: Do not repeat tags in question titles. Thank you.

Comment: Store in String if you need to keep formatting using your first example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to parse the date, and keep formatting

You need to keep the format alongside the `DateTime` if you want to. A `DateTime` does *not* have any concept of being in a particular format. The value of the `DateTime` returned by `Parse` isn't "10/01/2014 9:50:34 PM" - it's that particular date and time, but *not* a string representation.

You could have a type which maintains the two together - or if you always want to format in the same way, just specify that format explicitly when you format, without keeping it as data with the `DateTime` value.

Personally I would try to stick to `DateTime.ParseExact` where feasible, as I find it easier to predict what it will do - but it does depend on your input. If it's input with a particular format that you're expecting, `ParseExact` really is the way forward, potentially with the invariant culture to avoid any cultural differences.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the date now as a date

```
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
```

then when you need to display it with that formatting

```
String strNow = dateNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

If you have a date coming in with a format say in a String variable strNow and want to put it in the DateTime I would make sure to catch format exceptions

```
DateTime dateNow;

try {
dateNow = DateTime.ParseExact(strNow, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch (FormatException) {
//Log something or set a default date.
}
```

Comment: The display works perfectly, but when I need to parse a date of such a format it ruins it, and does some inbuilt conversions i guess (such as changing the 24 hour format)

Answer (score -1):

DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime, Format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);

for example:

DateTime.ParseExact(strNow, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite);